# Storing day, week and month stats in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, datetime

I've got a cron job which gathers stats for the previous day. Each morning it runs and updates `day`, `week` and `month` models.

```
day.rb 
belongs_to :week

week.rb
belongs_to :month
has_many :days

month.rb
has_many :weeks
belongs_to :foo
```

I'm planning on storing month and week as integers (so week commencing July 6th would be stored as 28). I was also thinking of doing the same with the day (so July 6th would be stored as 187). It means I'll also have to have a year field, so maybe this isn't the best approach?

Does anyone see any shortfalls in this system? I'll probably create a helper to do the conversions

How would you store the dates in a database like this? (I'm probably overthinking things and should just shut up and store dates, if so, feel free to let me know)

Comment: I wouldn't bother making models for day, month, and week.  I would just have a single model called "DayStats" or something which has a date field and a text field for the stats themselves, and whatever other associations you want (eg `belongs_to :foo`).  Why do you want to make records in the database for week X and year Y when that could all just be in a single date field?

Comment: Sorry, just read the last part of your question.  "Shut up and store dates" ;-)

Comment: I figured so I could sum the data, for efficiency. So if I wanted a year report grouped by week, I wouldn't have to get each individual day and add the values, I could just return the week modal. A query that returns 52 values is much quicker than returning 365 and grouping them into 52.

Comment: I should probably mention my Week and Month modals were going to have the sum of Day in them. Do you think this is overkill?

Comment: I'm confident you could do that with a `group by` query in sql, without it being a heavy hit on the database.

Comment: Thanks Max, i've done some googling which is confirming your thoughts too. Thank you